# Page not found (404)

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

Error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.100.10/accounts/profile/
Using the URLconf defined in urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^collect/
^member/
^accounts/login/$
^ ^$
^ ^contact/$
^ ^privacy-statement/$
^logout/$ [name='logout']
^data-admin/doc/
^accounts/password/reset/$
^accounts/password/reset/done/$
^accounts/password/reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$
^accounts/password/done/$
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, accounts/profile/, didn't match any of these.
```

This error occurs after login,it is accepting user name and password and it should successfully take to /index/ page but it is taking to accounts/profile/.If i remove the accounts/profile/ and run the ip,it is redirecting to the correct urls.

app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns(
    'zergit.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
  )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change the default [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) settings

By default, `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is set to `/accounts/profile/`. You clearly dont have a `/accounts/profile/` in your URLs, so you need to specify which URL you want to be redirected to once the login is successful.

Something like:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/' #Or whatever you wish
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL setting, just use the 'next' parameter and value in your account login url to redirect where ever you want. For example, the OP could have specified the requested login url as "http://192.168.100.10/accounts/login/?next=/index/"