# Authentication User Django Depending on the User

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm stuck on my django project, I used django default login system, everything works great here, I have 3 users, the first one gets an "Admin Panel" the second one gets a "Capture info panel" and the Third one can only sees the content printed by the other 2 users.

Myy questions are:

What do I need to give permissions to each user?
How can I redirect each panel to their respective user?

P.S. I already have the templates to each panel with their urls and views but I don't know how to show them.

Thanks in advance for taking your time to answer this newbies question but I just started working with this framework a week ago.

---

Update

Now I get a 404 error, instead of getting the page where I supposed to redirect.

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from .views import PanelRedirectView,PanelCapturista

urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^$' , 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name':'inicio/index.html'},
    name='login'),

url(r'cerrar/$' , 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', name='logout'),

url(r'^panel-capturista/$' , PanelCapturista.as_view() , name="panel-capturista"),
```

)

My views .py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView,TemplateView


class PanelRedirectView(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.groups.filter(name='gerente').count():
            return reverse_lazy('panel-gerente')
        elif user.groups.filter(name='capturista').count():
            return reverse_lazy('panel-capturista')
    else:
        return reverse_lazy('cliente')

class PanelCapturista(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'capturista/panel-capturista.html'
```

Answer (score 1):

something like (maybe reinventing the wheel)

```
class require_permission:
     def __init__(self,permission,redirect="index/denied_access"):
       self.perm = permission
       self.redirect = redirect

    @require_login
    def __call__(self,f):
        def fn(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
           if not request.user.has_perm(self.perm):
               redirect(self.redirect)
           return f(request,*args,**kwargs)
        return fn

 ...

 @require_permission(PERMISSION.CAN_VIEW_ADMIN,'index/capture_info')
 def admin_view(request,*args,**kw):
     return HttpResponse(...)

 @require_permission(PERMISSION.CAN_CAPTURE_INFO,'index/basic_user')
 def capture_view(request,*args,**kw):
      return HttpRespone(...)

 @require_login
 def basic_view(request,*args,**kw):
      return HttpResponse(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

**What do I need to give permissions to each user?**

What you're going to want here is a Group for each type of user (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#groups). E.G. 'Superuser', 'Normal User', and 'Restricted User'. These Groups can be created in the Django Admin Console and then each user can be assigned to their respective groups using the same Django Admin Console (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#managing-users-in-the-admin).

**How can I redirect each panel to their respective user?**

You will want to define a RedirectView that forwards to user's request to the expected "panel" view based on the user's assigned group (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview).

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

from articles.models import Article

class PanelRedirectView(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.groups.filter(name='superuser').count():
            return reverse('superuser-panel')
        elif user.groups.filter(name='regular_user').count():
            return reverse('regular-user-panel')
        else:
            return reverse('restricted-user-panel')
```

You can then use the annotations described by Joran to restricted access to the particular views being redirected to. The example I described uses restrictions based User Groups, whereas his answer uses restrictions based on User Permissions. This is more of a personal preference when dealing with a simple permission scheme like the one you are describing.

*** More Details ***

To redirect the user on login...

1. Create a named url for your redirect view in urls.py

   url(r'^panel-redirect/$' , PanelRedirectView.as_view() , name="panel-redirect"),
2. change LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in settings.py to point to this redirect view on login

   LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse('panel-redirect')

When the person logs in they will be redirected to the RedirectView, which in turn will redirect the person to the correct panel based on his/her assigned group

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this information Jeff, is this class and function defined on .models.py or views.py? Sorry I'm still a little confunsing with the MTV, thank you.

Comment: No problem! RedirectView is what Django calls a Class-based Generic View and you will place it in your views.py. These classes essentially encapsulate common view use cases and abstract away a lot of the common boilerplate code found in function based views. You can then override class behaviors through inheritance as shown above. Go ahead and give this video a view (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZQ5eFVQmu0). Russell Keith-Magee gives a well detailed explanation of why the community chose this class-based view route. Also check out this reference material http://ccbv.co.uk/.

Comment: Thank you Jeff I read the whole information you gave and I could really understand a bit more but now I got a different problem, I updated my problem, thanks again.

Comment: What url path are you calling to get a 404? You should have a url definition for each specific panel the way you have panel-capturista. You will then need a url definition for PanelRedirectView that you call in order to be redirected to the user group specified panel.

Comment: When I type my superuser on the log in panel I get this: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/
Using the URLconf defined in transcabrera.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^ ^$ [name='login']
^ cerrar/$ [name='logout']
^ ^accounts/panel-capturista/$ [name='panel-capturista']
^capturista/
The current URL, accounts/profile/, didn't match any of these   // I don't understand what's the problem :/

Comment: Have you defined LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in your settings.py? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407971/page-not-found-404)

Comment: Fixed the problema with LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL but I still can't figure out how can I redirect to each panel according to the user. I just get redirect to another URL but not the one I want to. Thanks for being helping me.

Comment: See *More Details* above

Comment: I did it, but no results, I got now another error, I think I am not understanding the concept as well, I got my files into a github reposetory, can you help me? https://github.com/AlejandroMAL/MultiPanel thank you.